# How to update a SliverAppBar widget outside of BlocBuilder on state change?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am trying to update the **SliverAppBar** widget's data on **BlocState** change. Since the SliverAppBar is not part of the BlocBuilder it doesn't update on state change. And calling setState() from the block results in the following error.

> This HomePage widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
> A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderErrorBox.

Here is my code...

```
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
int items = 121;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Material(
  child: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [setAppBar(), setContent()],
    ),
  ),
 );
}

 setAppBar() {
    return SliverAppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    floating: true,
    elevation: 1.0,
    forceElevated: true,
    centerTitle: false,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    title: Text("$items"));
   }

 setContent(){
     return BlocBuilder<MyBloc, MyState>(
     builder: (context, state) {
    if (state is DataLoadedState) {
      return SliverFillViewport(
      delegate:
            SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
          items = state.items;
          ///  
          /// **Want to update my items in the SliverAppBar from here ...** 
          ///
          return MyWidget();
        }, childCount: 1),
      );
    }
 }
```

How do I publish my changes to widgets outside the BlockBuilder scope ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The solution to this would be using a **BlocConsumer** in place of **BlocBuilder**. I implemented both a **BlocListener** and **BlocBuilder** inside **BlocConsumer**.

```
 setContent(){
    return BlocConsumer<HealthHomeBloc, HealthHomeState>(
      buildWhen: (previous, current) {
    return !(current is ItemUpdateState);
  }, builder: (context, state) {
     return ReuiredWidgetBasedOnState();
    
    }, listener: (context, state) {
      if(state is ItemUpdateState)
        setState(){
            items = state.items;
        }
   }, listenWhen: (previous, current) {
       return current is ItemUpdateState;
  });
}
```

So when we call setState this way, it doesn't interfere with the state of the builder. The BlocListener can publish our required state to the widgets outside the BlocBuilder